# Excel VBA error 91, trying to export certain sheets' data to text file

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro whereby it checks all sheetnames for certain criteria (specifically here the inclusion of 'TUBA' in the name) and, if met, exports a range on those sheets to text files with the sheet name as filename. I am getting error 91: object variable or With block variable not set, and on debugging the `If WS.name Like "TUBA*" Then` line is highlighted. How can I fix this? The problematic code is below. I previously had success with almost the same code but without the `If` statement (shown in the second block below), so I assume its the way I am adding this in. If i need to set a variable, which one have i missed?

```
Sub ExportTubatoText()

Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim output As String
Dim lngcount As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Name As String
Dim strFolder As String
strFolder = GetFolder("L:TUBA\")

'\ dialog box opens in that folder as default
'strFolder = GetFolder("L:TUBA\")

If strFolder <> "" Then

    MsgBox strFolder

End If

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'if worksheet has 'TUBA' in the title, then it is exported to text
    If WS.Name Like "TUBA*" Then
        output = ""
        For Each r In sh.Range("F3:F200").Rows
            For Each c In r.Cells
             output = output & c.Value
            Next c
            output = output & vbNewLine
        Next r
        Name = sh.Name
        Open strFolder & "\" & Name & ".txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, output
        Close
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Successful code:

```
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    output = ""
    For Each r In sh.Range("O2:O500").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
         output = output & c.Value
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Name = sh.Name
    Open strFolder & "\" & Name & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
Next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

`If WS.Name Like "TUBA*" Then`

to

`If sh.Name Like "TUBA*" Then`

Or change your For Each to `WS in...`

Comment: Just as a follow-on to this - `Option Explicit` would have flagged up this error immediately...

Comment: Rich, if this solved your problem, mark it as the answer.  If not, respond so you someone can try to help.

Comment: I now get a type mismatch error with the line `output = output & c.Value`. I've specified the `output` variable as string, but would this work with the decimals that are contained in the cells?

Rdster, apologies, been busy at work

Comment: If the value in those cells are going to be `Doubles`...then declare `output` as a `Double`instead

Comment: Looked into it further and there were some erroneous entries in the data. Fixing them sorted it so thanks for your original help!

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is just an idea and not an answer as @Rdster explain why your first code dos not work.

If you are working with only one column (like your both codes do) you can replace this part of your code:

```
For Each r In sh.Range("F3:F200").Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
     output = output & c.Value
    Next c
    output = output & vbNewLine
Next r
```

with this line:

```
output = Join(Application.Transpose(sh.Range("F3:F200").Value), vbNewLine)
```